# Show another field based on answer

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I have a form on my page showing Employee details.

I have a select field for `status` with the answers `Full Time` and `Part Time`

If the user selects Part Time I would like another field to appear which asks `Days per week`

Here is my Status question

```
 <select class="cs-select cs-skin-slide" name="status" data-init-plugin="cs-select">
 <option value='FT'>Full Time </option>
 <option value='PT'>Part Time </option>
 </select>
```

**UPDATE**

```
   <script> 
 $('#myselectbox').change(function(){
        var val = $('#myselectbox').val(); 
        if(val == FT){
           $('#forparttime').show();
        }else{
           $('#forfulltimetime').show();

        }

   });
          </script>

                                <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Employment Type</label>
                        <span class="help"></span><br>
                         <select id="myselectbox" class="cs-select cs-skin-slide" name="status" data-init-plugin="cs-select">
    <option value='FT'>Full Time </option>
    <option value='PT'>Part Time </option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" id="forparttime" name="forparttime" style="display:none" >
    <input type="text" id="forfulltimetime" name="forfulltimetime" style="display:none" >

 </div>
```

Comment: Shaun, any idea on how would you do that? It's a client side interaction, therefore PHP or Java will not help much in solving it... Try looking into Javascript.

Comment: Have a look at  this ... http://plugins.krajee.com/dependent-dropdown/demo

Comment: plese see my below comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 **<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
 <script> 
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $('#myselectbox').change(function(){
      var val = $('#myselectbox').val(); 
      if(val == 'FT'){
       $('#forparttime').hide();
       $('#forfulltimetime').show();
    }else{
       $('#forfulltimetime').hide();
       $('#forparttime').show();
      }
    });

    });
      </script>
  <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Employment Type</label>
                    <span class="help"></span><br>
                     <select id="myselectbox" class="cs-select cs-skin-slide" name="status" data-init-plugin="cs-select">
<option value='FT'>Full Time </option>
<option value='PT'>Part Time </option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="forparttime" placeholder="forparttime" name="forparttime" style="display:none" >
<input type="text" id="forfulltimetime" placeholder="forfulltimetime" name="forfulltimetime" style="display:none" >
</div>**
```

Comment: is it live or in local?

Comment: I cant unfortunatley as the HR system is restricted by Data Protection

Comment: check now i have updated again. now its working in my local

Comment: Ah that works, however I only need the extra field for Part time

Answer (score 1):

If there is only two option for status, first I would like to suggest you to use boolean value. And also consider using id for select then display or hide the field using this value with jquery. something like

`if ( $('.cs-select').val()){ $( '#ur_field' ).hide() }`

or

`if ( $('#select_box_id').val()){ $( '#ur_field' ).hide() }`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

**HTML:**

```
 <select class="cs-select cs-skin-slide" name="status" data-init-plugin="cs-select">
     <option value='FT'>Full Time </option>
     <option value='PT'>Part Time </option>
 </select>

 <input type="text" id="forparttime" name="forparttime" style="display:none" >
 <input type="text" id="forfulltimetime" name="forfulltimetime" style="display:none" >
```

**JS:**

```
$(".cs-select").change(function(){

    var value = this.value;

    if (value == "FT"){
        $(".your-field-shown").show();
        $(".your-field-hidden").hide();
    }

    elseif (value == "PT"){
        $(".your-field-shown").hide();
        $(".your-field-hidden").show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Shuan I updated my answer, have a look and let me know if it worked for you.

Comment: Hi Chris - Still now showing for some reason - I have copied your code exactly...

Comment: Are you using a CMS like WordPress or is it a static HTML site?